# Product Flavors in Android

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have 2 product flavors in an Android project.

I want to use a code base, and I have some code like:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("firstApp")) {
        webButton = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.webButton);
        webButton.setBackgroundColor(Util.getColorFromString(""));
        webButton.setIconColor(Util.getColorFromString("#005126"));
}
```

First App has a layout and it has a button with id webButton.

But in the second app's layout, I don't need the webButton, so I removed it.

But the code above is giving error, because second app doesn't have the button.

What is the way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new xml file in `values/` that contains the follow resource:

```
<item type="id" name="webButton"/>
```

and you are good to go.